# Configurar Web Service para que responda en JSON

Tags: ajax, json, webservice

buen día.
Recientemente desarrolle un WS con varios métodos, que se conectan a SQL server. Estoy tratando de consumirlos a través de Ajax, investigando sobre este tema me tope que para realizar esta acción, mi WS debe de responder en formato JSON, entiendo que nativamente el WS (desarrollado en Visual) responde en formato XML. Mis dudas son: Es correcto que para consumir el WS por Ajax, este tiene que responder en JSON? y la segunda duda es como configuro mi WS para que responda en formato JSON. Adjunto código de un método:

```
[WebMethod]
    public String[] InsertxWEBUsers(Session _session, xWEBUsers _xWEBUsers)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();

        try
        {
            con = this.conection(_session);

            this.check(con);

            xWEBUsers ReleasexWEBUsers = this.initxWEBUsers(con, _xWEBUsers);

            con.Open();

            if (this.validateField(ReleasexWEBUsers.cpnyid.Trim(), ReleasexWEBUsers.custId.Trim(), ReleasexWEBUsers.userId.Trim(), con))
            {
                this.throwException("El UserId " + ReleasexWEBUsers.userId.Trim() + " ya existe en la compañia " + ReleasexWEBUsers.cpnyid.Trim() + " y en el cliente " + ReleasexWEBUsers.custId.Trim() +"");
            }

            this.validatexWEBUsers(ReleasexWEBUsers, con);

            SqlCommand cmd = this.commandInsertxWEBUsers(ReleasexWEBUsers, con);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();


        }

        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }
        return strArray;
    }
```

Como dato adicional, investigando en internet me encontré con JSON.net una especie de complemento para poder conseguir que el WS responda en JSON, pero ni así funcionó.

Les agradezco su atención, y quedo atento a sus comentarios, gracias.

Saludos!!!

Anexo la llamada Ajax para invocar mi Ws:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://devsyshyperv6:8080/xWSRMSUser.asmx/StatusxWEBUsers",
    data: "{ session: '" + session + "', xwEBUsers: " + xwEBUsers + "}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(r) {
        alert(r.d);
    },
    error: function(r) {
        alert(r.responseText);
    },
    failure: function(r) {
        alert(r.responseText);
    }
});
return false;
```

es correcto?

Answer (score 1):

Agrega a tu `WebMethod`

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
```

Agregando esta linea dices que el formato de respuesta de tu funcion o metodo es Json.

Comment: @Mariano editado!

Comment: Ya agregue la línea como lo indicas, al final en el return tengo que agregar algo mas?

Comment: No, ya que estas diciendo que lo que devuelva sera JSON.

Comment: Nueva duda, como puedo testear que el método devuelve el JSON?, ya reconstrui la solución, incluso ya la publique en un iis, como puedo probar?

Comment: Puedes ocupar postman o llamar desde tu codigo haciendo una llamada ajax!

Comment: Anexe mi Ajax, crees que esta correcto?

Comment: si, te funciono @iRaver?

Comment: Tendras algún tutorial de Postman?

Comment: Postman es una aplicacion, debes descargarla y seguir los pasos, seleccionar el tipo de metodo (GET o POST, por ejemplo) los headers de la peticion y agregar los campos que envias, busca en youtube debe haber miles de usos

Comment: ya realice una prueba utilizando postman, arme el header con los parámetros que solicita el método, dos cosas la primera es que la respuesta del web service contiene la estructura del método pero no me devuelve ningún dato, y lo segundo es que sigue devolviendo respuesta en formato xml. Nueva duda, otra forma de saber si el ws responde en JSON, podría ser cuando abres el ws en un navegador? es decir cuando lo abres en el navegador te muestra la estructura del ws y el formato que es xml, si responde en JSON se tendría que ver el formato en el navegador?

Answer (score 0):

es correcto, originalmente los servicios web están hechos para retornar la información en formato XML, podrías usar WCF que tiene múltiples beneficios ante los servicios web. Pero no te asustes, si es posible que un servicio web pueda retornar la informacion en formato Json, aqui te dejo un excelente tutorial. Saludos.

[Tutorial Servicio Web Formato Json](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/8ef97c/web-service-in-Asp-Net-part-4/)